# How can I make div's of 100% page width, which do not use: position: fixed; so as the page is scrollable

Tags: html

I am making a page whereby there is a header and main image which need to be 100% page width. Although i need to be able to scroll down the page, therefore i need to a way to make the `div` 100% page width without a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking in something like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar ?

The simplest way is ( [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jxgFM/) ):

```
.navbar {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(http://www.phing.info/trac/chrome/site/logo.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    /*background-size: cover;*/
    background-size: contain;
}​
```

Comment: How would I do that in terms of CSS?